# How to Obtain the MSI 'UILevel' Property From a C++ Custom Action

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to get at the 'UILevel' MSI property from within a C++ custom action in order to determine whether or not the user is running in 'no UI mode', but am not having much luck. The function I am calling is passed the MSIHANDLE from a function which I export in my DLL (which may be either a 'deferred' or 'firstsequence' action). What I'm seeing is that `MsiGetPropertyW` is always returning `ERROR_MORE_DATA` and the `trueLength` field is always 0. Here is my code:

```
bool runningInNoUIMode(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
    unsigned long nBufLen = 64UL;
    WCHAR *wszValue = new WCHAR[nBufLen];

    DWORD trueLength = 0UL;
    UINT result = ::MsiGetPropertyW(hInstall, L"UILevel", L"", &trueLength); // Get the size of the property value first to see if there is enough storage allocated.
    if (ERROR_MORE_DATA == result || nBufLen <= trueLength)
    {
        if (NULL != wszValue)
        {
            delete [] wszValue;
        }

        // Allocate more memory for the property adding one for the null terminator.
        nBufLen = trueLength + 1;
        wszValue = new WCHAR[nBufLen];
    }

    if (NULL == wszValue)
    {
        WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Unable to determine the user interface level the MSI is being run with because we were unable to allocate storage for accessing the 'UILevel' property.");
        return false;
    }

    memset(wszValue, L'\0', nBufLen * sizeof(WCHAR));
    result = ::MsiGetPropertyW(hInstall, L"UILevel", wszValue, &trueLength);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != result)
    {
        WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Unable to determine the user interface level the MSI is being run with, error code = '%lu'.", result);
        delete [] wszValue;
        return false;
    }

    if (0 == wcscmp(L"2", wszValue)) // INSTALLUILEVEL_NONE == 2
    {
        delete [] wszValue;
        return true;
    }

    delete [] wszValue;
    return false;
}
```

I believe I can work around this for now by passing the 'UILevel' property through WiX and checking for it that way in the C++, but I am curious what the problem here is as well.

I'm using Visual Studio/Visual C++ 2010 on Windows 7 with WiX 3.5.2519.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: Just a guess, this sentence on MSDN makes me think: "If the value for the property retrieved by the MsiGetProperty function is not defined, it is equivalent to a 0-length value. It is not an error."

Comment: Yes, true. I know about that, but I am not sure it applies since the return code is ERROR_MORE_DATA instead of ERROR_SUCCESS. Besides, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx says that UILevel is set by the installer ("The installer sets the UILevel property to the level of the user interface."). However, when I look at the installer in Orca, I can see that there is no UILevel property set anywhere (for a default).

Comment: What happens if you preallocated a buffer of, say, 256 bytes, and set `trueLength = 256` on the initial call to `MsiGetProperty`? Does it return the correct value then? Not related: UILevel is set by Windows installer and isn't authored in the installer database.

Comment: @DanielGehriger I tried your suggestion and `MsiGetPropertyW` returns `trueLength = 0` and the buffer is the empty string. So, it looks like that property is not defined when I hit this code for some reason.

Comment: @Joe: when is the CA scheduled? This may affect the result.

Comment: @DanielGehriger It depends. It may be before LaunchConditions or after CostFinalize. The tests I've been debugging through have all been the latter.

Comment: But is it deferred? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368268(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @DanielGehriger And in another case after RemoveFiles.

Comment: @DanielGehriger Yes, in some instances it is deferred (as I mentioned in the original question).

Comment: Corrected the link - but I'm at loss with further ideas.

Comment: Well, being deferred may actually be the problem. I haven't tested that yet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yep, that's got to be it. I just debugged through a custom action scheduled as `firstsequence` and before `LaunchConditions` and it worked perfectly. I'll post an answer below. Thanks again, @DanielGehriger!

Comment: This says MsiGetProperty only supports a limited set of properties  [Obtaining Context Information for Deferred Execution Custom Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/13174c5d-c810-4b5d-9d1e-60ed30b8c44d)

Comment: @MarkRovetta Thank you for the link. I wish I would have know that a few days ago :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DanielGehriger, we figured out that the problem isn't with the code, but with the scheduling for the custom action. The `UILevel` MSI property is simply *not available* when running a `deferred` custom action (I found that the code worked correctly for a custom action scheduled for `firstsequence`). I have worked around this limitation by explicitly passing it on custom action data using WiX:

```
<CustomAction Id="CustomAction.SetProperty" Property="CustomActionCall"
  Value="UILEVEL=[UILevel];" />
```

and then checking for this in the C++ with `WcaIsPropertySet` and `WcaGetProperty`. Note that the character case of the property name between square brackets matters here.

Comment: Also, thanks go to @ChristopherPainter, Mark Rovetta, and Adriano to some extent. This is a very helpful link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: This might be an interesting read for you: http://blog.iswix.com/2011/10/beam-me-up-using-json-to-serialize.html

Answer (score 1):

Another way of making this simpler is to use the [MsiEvaluateCondition function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370104%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
BOOL bUI = MsiEvaluateCondition(L"UILevel<3");
```

in C# using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsIntaller (DTF) it's:

```
var uiLevel = session["UILevel"];
```

In C++ there's a sample at [MsiGetProperty function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
UINT __stdcall MyCustomAction(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
    TCHAR* szValueBuf = NULL;
    DWORD cchValueBuf = 0;
    UINT uiStat =  MsiGetProperty(hInstall, TEXT("MyProperty"), TEXT(""), &cchValueBuf);
    //cchValueBuf now contains the size of the property's string, without null termination
    if (ERROR_MORE_DATA == uiStat)
    {
        ++cchValueBuf; // add 1 for null termination
        szValueBuf = new TCHAR[cchValueBuf];
        if (szValueBuf)
        {
            uiStat = MsiGetProperty(hInstall, TEXT("MyProperty"), szValueBuf, &cchValueBuf);
        }
    }
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != uiStat)
    {
        if (szValueBuf != NULL) 
           delete[] szValueBuf;
        return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
    }

    // custom action uses MyProperty
    // ...

    delete[] szValueBuf;

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I found that on MSDN too (my example C++ is similar; the major difference is the use of WCHAR instead of TCHAR - which I hope does not matter!). I don't think you read my question fully; this does not work for me.

Comment: MsiEvaluateCondition(L"UILevel<3") is a good idea. I'll give this a try. Thanks!

Comment: This did not work either (see my answer below for details). Thanks anyway!

Comment: I can assume it doesn't work for you otherwise you wouldn't be asking for help. :)  This is the most help I can conjure up since I think it's borderline psychotic to be programming in C/C++ these days. :)  I mean that in a half joking half serious way.

Comment: Deferred CA's don't have full access to the MSI Handle.  You have to marshal the data over as CustomActionData.  Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370543(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yep. That's what I did. I don't have a choice as to what language I'm using. Blame the people who wrote this code 15 years ago :)

Comment: I've ported plenty of C++ to C# custom actions.  You just ignore about 9 out of 10 lines to see what really needs to be done. :)

Comment: I would port it if I had the time and interest. We might be trashing all this in a year.